# intra python flask server REST call

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to call a flask POST API from within another POST API.

**It simply hangs there. I am using 'requests'.**

```
nsr = requests.post('http://<public_ip>:8000/auto_infer/ns', json = json_data)
```

The API call runs from python console.. I am sure I am missing some conf or something.

Comment: Please make sure theres no circular dependencies are there. And also please elaborate your question like the URLs and what's the json data the other API is expecting. I guess the there will a circular loop

Comment: Have you tried the request from a http client such as postman or insomnia?

Comment: Yes, I tried POSTMAN. It hangs up there. Found a resolve though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to server running in a single thread configuration. So, anything external was able to access but internally that lone thread was preoccupied while calling.